# How to parse a text file to xml format with specific field names?

Tags: xml, database, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a text files which are in ascii format. But I would like to convert the data inside the files to xml format. My data are basically http get requests. I have put a data sample below. If anyone knows how to parse this kind of data please share the solution or at least a head start. Eventually my target is to dump those data in a mysql database. I don't have any language or platform preferences. So, whatever works I will go with that. I would appreciate your response.

```
131.162.134.169: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1675772700"
Last-Modified: Fri, 30 Sep 2011 07:41:01 GMT
Content-Length: 10198
Date: Sat, 24 May 2014 23:19:06 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.25-devel-fb150ff

<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/web/css/style.css?v20">
<script language="javascript" src="/web/jquery/js/jquery_1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/jquery/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/jquery/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/function/rc4.js"></script>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/web/css/button_style.css">
<style>

body, html {margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
background-repeat:
131.162.207.119: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found


131.162.200.38: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 May 2014 23:19:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Feb 2010 13:40:38 GMT
ETag: "57ef4-f8-f24d4180"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 248
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML> 
 <HEAD> 
  <TITLE>E.C. Smith Herbarium</TITLE>
         <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;
          URL=http://herbarium.acadiau.ca"> 
 </HEAD> 
 <BODY>
  <P><B><FONT FACE="Arial">E.C. Smith Herbarium</FONT></B></P> 
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

There are hundreds of lines like this in the files. But it has specific pattern like One IP and then their response data. The total html body parts will be on one xml field.

Comment: Hmm, you say ASCII but the meta tag in the first example says UTF-8.

Comment: everything in the file are in plain text even those meta tags.  @TomBlodget